# Google Tag Manager View tag firing order in preview

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a few tags in tag manager all are set to standard firing except one that I have set a higher priority to fire first.

Is there a way in the preview to see that it actually is firing first.

Secondly is there a way to ensure a tag fires before the page changes similar to what you can do with links?

Comment: Do you have installed "Tag Assistant (by Google)" extension in Chrome?
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk

Answer (score 0):

You can see all your fired tags and their order using "Tag Assistant (by Google)" extension in Chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk

Comment: Hi Vasiliy, Thats not the right type of tags mate. Sorry I know tag assitant thats for checking things like GTM & GA im taking about Tag managers own tags